# Split string into variables

Tags: php

I have the following string: `157458210148`

The first 10 character represents something to me so I split it using the `substr()` function like this:

```
$pin= "157458210148";
$order_num  = substr($pin,0,10);
```

My question is, how do I return the rest of the string and assign it to a variable?

Example  `$id = 48`

Comment: Same way `$order_num  = substr($pin,10);`

Comment: Why didn't you give start parameter? I thought It was required

Comment: You should **absolutely** and **quickly** take the habit to always read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an alternative to get both at one time:

```
list($order_num, $other_num)  = str_split($pin, 10);
```

Or just do it again the same way:

```
$other_num = substr($pin, 10);
```

Comment: This is powerful ...I also use list() when programming for FILE UPLOAD . Its very useful Thanks

Comment: That's one "hot" answer you have there ;-) So hot, someone else used it *lol*

Comment: Ha I see, and they even got an upvote!  Maybe it was the `//comments`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's about all that's different. Man... can't people be "original"? *lol*

Answer (score 4):

Just take another substring starting from the postion that you need:

```
$pin= "157458210148";
$order_num = substr($pin,0,10);
// if you don't set 3rd parameter - all symbols till end of string will be taken
$rest = substr($pin, 10);
var_dump($order_num, $rest);
// outputs string(10) "1574582101" string(2) "48"
```